# Clear way of using XPath to find elements which contain a given child element?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this XML:

```
<Catalog>
    <CUnit id="Bd">
        <Race value="T1"/>
    </CUnit>
    <CUnit id="Critter">
    </CUnit>
    <CUnit id="Ld">
        <Race value="T1"/>
    </CUnit>
</Catalog>
```

I want to use XPath to extract the CUnit elements that have a Race child element. Is there a clearer way than this?

```
CUnit/Race/..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Avoid using the `//` pseudo-operator**, because with many XPath engines it is implemented very inefficiently (causes traversal of the whole subtree rooted in the context node).

**Whenever the structure of the XML document is well-known, use specific paths.**

**In this case**:

```
/*/CUnit[Race]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a [predicate](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates) instead:

```
//CUnit[Race]
```